# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get') error when updating graph method runs a second time Neo4j

Tags: node.js, mongodb, neo4j, cypher

In my server I use both MongoDB and Neo4j, and when I update a mongo product record I also update Neo4j product node and relationship to a category node. I use a mongo transaction so if anything fails consistence is maintained across the two dbs.
In my mongo update method I can either update rating or the whole record,so I set up tests to do both.

I pass to the Neo4j update method the js object from returning the updated mongo record, for the first test I modify the category parameter, so in Neo4j it first deletes the relationship to the old category, then it updates the product node and creates a relationship to the new category.

The first test passes ( update category), but when the second test runs (updating rating) it fails as the Neo4j method throws `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')` error.

I actually modified the cypher as my first draft ( the commented out one) wasn't updating relationship to the category node and both tests passed.

Thinking that the problem might be that in the second test there is no difference in category I duplicate the first test and indeed the second time it doesn't pass either.

Can you please spot what am I doing wrong?
Many thanks.

## Neo4J

```
exports.updateProductById = async (product) => {
    console.log('Neo4j updateProductById product is : ', product);
    const driver = neo4j.getDriver();
    const session = driver.session();
    const json = JSON.stringify(product);
    const res = await session.executeWrite(tx => tx.run(

      // `
      // with apoc.convert.fromJsonMap($json) as json
      // match (p:Product {id: json.id}) set p = json
      // with p, json
      // match (s:Shop)-[r:SELLS]->(p)-[r2:IN_CATEGORY]->(c:Category)
      // set r.productId = json.id, c.name = json.category
      // RETURN p as product,s as shop, r as relSells, r2 as relCategory
      // `

      
      `
      with apoc.convert.fromJsonMap($json) as json

      match (p:Product {id: json.id})
      match (s:Shop)-[r:SELLS]->(p)-[rOld:IN_CATEGORY]->(c:Category) 
      where c.name = p.category
      set p = json
      delete rOld
      merge (p)-[rNew:IN_CATEGORY]->(cat: category {name : json.category})
      set rNew.productId = json.id
      RETURN p as product, s as shop, r as relSells, rNew as relCategory, rOld as relOld, c as catOld, cat as category
      `
      ,{json: json }
    )).catch((error) => {
      console.log('Neo4j updateProductById error: ', error);
    });
    
    await session.close();
    console.log(`Neo4j updateProductById modified ${res.records.length} products`);
    const updatedProduct = res.records[0].get('product');
    const shop = res.records[0].get('shop');
    const relSells = res.records[0].get('relSells');
    const relCategory = res.records[0].get('relCategory');
    const category = res.records[0].get('category');


    const catOld = res.records[0].get('catOld');
    const relOld = res.records[0].get('relOld');
    
    console.log('Neo4j updateProductById modified product is: ', updatedProduct);
    console.log('Neo4j updateProductById shop is: ', shop);
    console.log('Neo4j updateProductById modified relSells is: ', relSells);
    console.log('Neo4j updateProductById modified relCategory is: ', relCategory);

    console.log('Neo4j updateProductById modified category is: ', category);

    console.log('Neo4j updateProductById old category is: ', catOld);
    console.log('Neo4j updateProductById old relCategory is: ', relOld);
    
    return updatedProduct;

  }
```

## Whole record update console logs

```
Mongoose updateProductById:  {
  _id: new ObjectId("63417b1e6073ddba42d0ddf3"),
  createdOnDate: 1638894572905,
  name: 'someNewName',
  brand: 'someCategory',
  price: 12,
  description: 'description',
  category: 'Bikes',
  city: 'Bologna',
  region: 'Emilia-Romagna',
  country: 'Italy',
  vendor: 'fixit',
  vendorId: 'test2',
  barcode: 'some',
  imageUrl: 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fix-it-b4b00.appspot.com/o/Products%2F61af8bec02edbe24ce034963?alt=media&token=a891dc05-407e-43d2-ab2b-0f49226249a9',
  fullImages: [],
  thumbNails: [],
  minimumStock: 10,
  availableQuantity: 10,
  soldQuantity: 0,
  isPromotion: false,
  totalRating: 0,
  ratings: 0,
  createdAt: 2022-10-08T13:29:02.880Z,
  updatedAt: 2022-10-08T13:29:02.961Z,
  __v: 0,
  averageRating: 0,
  id: '63417b1e6073ddba42d0ddf3'
}
Neo4j updateProductById product is :  {
  _id: new ObjectId("63417b1e6073ddba42d0ddf3"),
  createdOnDate: 1638894572905,
  name: 'someNewName',
  brand: 'someCategory',
  price: 12,
  description: 'description',
  category: 'Bikes',
  city: 'Bologna',
  region: 'Emilia-Romagna',
  country: 'Italy',
  vendor: 'fixit',
  vendorId: 'test2',
  barcode: 'some',
  imageUrl: 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fix-it-b4b00.appspot.com/o/Products%2F61af8bec02edbe24ce034963?alt=media&token=a891dc05-407e-43d2-ab2b-0f49226249a9',
  fullImages: [],
  thumbNails: [],
  minimumStock: 10,
  availableQuantity: 10,
  soldQuantity: 0,
  isPromotion: false,
  totalRating: 0,
  ratings: 0,
  createdAt: 2022-10-08T13:29:02.880Z,
  updatedAt: 2022-10-08T13:29:02.961Z,
  __v: 0,
  averageRating: 0,
  id: '63417b1e6073ddba42d0ddf3'
}
Neo4j updateProductById modified 1 products
Neo4j updateProductById modified product is:  Node {
  identity: Integer { low: 2, high: 0 },
  labels: [ 'Product' ],
  properties: {
    country: 'Italy',
    isPromotion: false,
    city: 'Bologna',
    vendorId: 'test2',
    description: 'description',
    fullImages: [],
    soldQuantity: Integer { low: 0, high: 0 },
    createdAt: '2022-10-08T13:29:02.880Z',
    price: Integer { low: 12, high: 0 },
    ratings: Integer { low: 0, high: 0 },
    vendor: 'fixit',
    averageRating: Integer { low: 0, high: 0 },
    __v: Integer { low: 0, high: 0 },
    imageUrl: 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fix-it-b4b00.appspot.com/o/Products%2F61af8bec02edbe24ce034963?alt=media&token=a891dc05-407e-43d2-ab2b-0f49226249a9',
    minimumStock: Integer { low: 10, high: 0 },
    id: '63417b1e6073ddba42d0ddf3',
    brand: 'someCategory',
    barcode: 'some',
    updatedAt: '2022-10-08T13:29:02.961Z',
    thumbNails: [],
    availableQuantity: Integer { low: 10, high: 0 },
    totalRating: Integer { low: 0, high: 0 },
    createdOnDate: Integer { low: -1782934167, high: 381 },
    name: 'someNewName',
    _id: '63417b1e6073ddba42d0ddf3',
    category: 'Bikes',
    region: 'Emilia-Romagna'
  },
  elementId: '2'
}
Neo4j updateProductById shop is:  Node {
  identity: Integer { low: 1, high: 0 },
  labels: [ 'Shop' ],
  properties: { id: 'test2' },
  elementId: '1'
}
Neo4j updateProductById modified relSells is:  Relationship {
  identity: Integer { low: 5, high: 0 },
  start: Integer { low: 1, high: 0 },
  end: Integer { low: 2, high: 0 },
  type: 'SELLS',
  properties: { productId: '63417b1e6073ddba42d0ddf3' },
  elementId: '5',
  startNodeElementId: '1',
  endNodeElementId: '2'
}
Neo4j updateProductById modified relCategory is:  Relationship {
  identity: Integer { low: 1, high: 0 },
  start: Integer { low: 2, high: 0 },
  end: Integer { low: 8, high: 0 },
  type: 'IN_CATEGORY',
  properties: { productId: '63417b1e6073ddba42d0ddf3' },
  elementId: '1',
  startNodeElementId: '2',
  endNodeElementId: '8'
}
Neo4j updateProductById modified category is:  Node {
  identity: Integer { low: 8, high: 0 },
  labels: [ 'category' ],
  properties: { name: 'Bikes' },
  elementId: '8'
}
Neo4j updateProductById old category is:  Node {
  identity: Integer { low: 4, high: 0 },
  labels: [ 'Category' ],
  properties: { name: 'Safety and locks' },
  elementId: '4'
}
Neo4j updateProductById old relCategory is:  Relationship {
  identity: Integer { low: 0, high: 0 },
  start: Integer { low: -1, high: -1 },
  end: Integer { low: -1, high: -1 },
  type: '',
  properties: {},
  elementId: '0',
  startNodeElementId: '-1',
  endNodeElementId: '-1'
}
Mongoose updateProductById Neo4j updated product
transacion wasn't aborted
committing session 
ending session
```

## Update rating console logs

```
Mongoose updateProductById rating:  {
  _id: new ObjectId("63417b1e6073ddba42d0ddf3"),
  createdOnDate: 1638894572905,
  name: 'someNewName',
  brand: 'someCategory',
  price: 12,
  description: 'description',
  category: 'Bikes',
  city: 'Bologna',
  region: 'Emilia-Romagna',
  country: 'Italy',
  vendor: 'fixit',
  vendorId: 'test2',
  barcode: 'some',
  imageUrl: 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fix-it-b4b00.appspot.com/o/Products%2F61af8bec02edbe24ce034963?alt=media&token=a891dc05-407e-43d2-ab2b-0f49226249a9',
  fullImages: [],
  thumbNails: [],
  minimumStock: 10,
  availableQuantity: 10,
  soldQuantity: 0,
  isPromotion: false,
  totalRating: 5,
  ratings: 1,
  createdAt: 2022-10-08T13:29:02.880Z,
  updatedAt: 2022-10-08T13:29:03.096Z,
  __v: 0,
  averageRating: 5,
  id: '63417b1e6073ddba42d0ddf3'
}
Neo4j updateProductById product is :  {
  _id: new ObjectId("63417b1e6073ddba42d0ddf3"),
  createdOnDate: 1638894572905,
  name: 'someNewName',
  brand: 'someCategory',
  price: 12,
  description: 'description',
  category: 'Bikes',
  city: 'Bologna',
  region: 'Emilia-Romagna',
  country: 'Italy',
  vendor: 'fixit',
  vendorId: 'test2',
  barcode: 'some',
  imageUrl: 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fix-it-b4b00.appspot.com/o/Products%2F61af8bec02edbe24ce034963?alt=media&token=a891dc05-407e-43d2-ab2b-0f49226249a9',
  fullImages: [],
  thumbNails: [],
  minimumStock: 10,
  availableQuantity: 10,
  soldQuantity: 0,
  isPromotion: false,
  totalRating: 5,
  ratings: 1,
  createdAt: 2022-10-08T13:29:02.880Z,
  updatedAt: 2022-10-08T13:29:03.096Z,
  __v: 0,
  averageRating: 5,
  id: '63417b1e6073ddba42d0ddf3'
}
Neo4j updateProductById modified 0 products
Mongoose updateProductById Neo4j error:  TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')
    at exports.updateProductById (/Users/vincenzocalia/server-node/api/src/neo4j/product_neo4j.js:132:43)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async exports.updateProductById (/Users/vincenzocalia/server-node/api/src/controllers/product.controller.js:840:9)
Transaction error is: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')
    at exports.updateProductById (/Users/vincenzocalia/server-node/api/src/neo4j/product_neo4j.js:132:43)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async exports.updateProductById (/Users/vincenzocalia/server-node/api/src/controllers/product.controller.js:840:9)
transacion was aborted
ending session
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem being I use merge for the entire pattern where `(cat: Category)` might need to be created, while `(p)` existed already

`merge (p)-[rNew:IN_CATEGORY]->(cat: Category {name : json.category})` as mentioned in the docs

> When using MERGE on full patterns, the behavior is that either the whole pattern matches, or the whole pattern is created. MERGE will not partially use existing patterns — it is all or nothing. If partial matches are needed, this can be accomplished by splitting a pattern up into multiple MERGE clauses.

So after splitting it as follows it worked as intended.

```
`
      with apoc.convert.fromJsonMap($json) as json

      match (p:Product {id: json.id})
      match (s:Shop)-[r:SELLS]->(p)-[rOld:IN_CATEGORY]->(c:Category) 
      where c.name = p.category
      set p = json
      delete rOld
      merge (cat: Category {name : json.category})
      merge (p)-[rNew:IN_CATEGORY]->(cat)
      set rNew.productId = json.id
      RETURN p as product, s as shop, r as relSells, rNew as relCategory, rOld as relOld, c as catOld, cat as category
      `
```

Hope this will help other starting with Neo4j.
Cheers